# Gensim build_vocab taking too long

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, word2vec, gensim

I'm trying to train a doc2vec model using the gensim library on 50 million sentences of variable length.

Some tutorials (eg. https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb) have a `model.build_vocab` step before the actual training process. This part has been running for 3 hours now without any updates.

Is this step necessary for the training process? Why could this step be taking so long since it's just a linear pass over the data?

Using gensim version 3.4.0 with python 3.6.0

Comment: Try `progress_per` parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `build_vocab()` step to discover all words, then set-up the known-vocabulary structures, is required. (Though, if you supply your corpus as an argument to `Doc2Vec`, both the `build_vocab()` and `train()` will be done automatically.)

You should enable Python logging at the INFO level to see logged information about the progress of this, and other long-running gensim steps. This will help you see if progress is truly being made, or has stopped or slowed at some point.

If the vocabulary-discovery starts fast but then slows, perhaps your system has too little memory and has begun using very-slow virtual memory (swapping). If it seems to stop, perhaps there's a silent error in your method of reading the corpus. If it's just slow the whole way, perhaps there's something wrong with your method of reading the corpus.

Comment: Since `build_vocab` just discovers words, and no actual training is done, I could then just pass a set of all new words it needs to know, without the context of actual sentences, right?

Comment: My problem is that I ran `build_vocab` on a huge corpus, without also including the phrases. I haven't run `train` just yet. So I thought I could glean off all the phrases and input the set into `build_vocab`. Then I'll still have a chance to train vectors for phrases later.

Comment: The vocabulary survey results, as done by `build_vocab()`, should match the frequencies of words actually seen in each training-pass. So the act of patching an existing count to now account for a phrases-transformation – both decrementing unigram counts, and adding new composite-tokens – may be just as complex as just running `build_vocab()` on the updated, phrase-transformed corpus.

Comment: But in this [page](https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/) by Radim Řehůřek, he says, `build_vocab(some_sentences)` followed by `train(other_sentences)`. So if those other sentences didn't have to go through `build_vocab`, then there's no point in that method (`build_vocab`) keeping the frequencies of words.

Comment: I don't understand your point. A Word2Vec/Doc2Vec model needs an accurate idea of word-frequencies for the data it will be trained on. It gets that via `build_vocab()`. You should run `build_vocab()` on the same corpus as you `train()`. Trying to reuse data collected during a prior `build_vocab()` call, on a slightly-earlier (no phrases) version of the same corpus, but patching it with cahnges caused by phrase-ification, would be sufficiently complicated and error-prone I doubt it would save much effort. I recommend the earlier run be put aside, & run `build_vocab()` fresh on final corpus.

Comment: I now get your point. The wording in that blog threw me off (sorry, not a native english speaker). So now if I save my Word2Vec model and want to train it on a different corpus, I need to run `build_vocab(new_corpus)` and then `train(new_corpus)` right?

Comment: If it's a large & new corpus, you probably just want to start with an all-new model, because calling `build_vocab(new_corpus)` again essentially resets the model. It's possible to call `train()` with new data on an old model, without starting fresh, but (1) new words won't be recognized; (2) word-frequencies for sampling actions will only be based on the 'old' data; (3) words only in the 'old' set get no interleaved updates so drift arbitrarily away from those receiving updates, in proportion to how much training & your chosen followup-training `alpha` rates.

Comment: In Word2Vec there's also a `build_vocab(..., update=True)` option but while it expands the vocabulary, it still has issue (3) above & other complications wtih-regard to word-frequencies & balance-between-before-and-after-sesssions, too complicated to discuss in this tangent. If you have a significantly expanded or transformed corpus, starting a fresh model is the most robust, repeatable, straightforward option.